# How can I make a question keep repeating each time you answer it?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python, and I have a random password generator where the user types out the word 'generate' (my take on a button, if there is a better way please tell me) to get a new word.  It generates a random word, joins it with a random number, then again a random word and then prints it.  The issue is that I have just copied and pasted the code that runs each time, to be able to keep generating new passwords.  What command can I use to loop this question?.
Heres my code:

```
value = input("Type 'generate' to generate a new password.\n")
    if value == 'generate':
        line = open("words.txt").read()
        line = line[0:] 

        words = line.split() 
        one = random.choice(words)

        line = open("numbers.txt").read()
        line = line[0:]

        numbers = line.split()
        two = random.choice(numbers)

        line = open("words.txt").read()
        line = line[0:]

        words2 = line.split()
        three = random.choice(words2)
        print('Your new password is '+(one)+(two)+(three))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restart my program in Python? (see code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851836/how-do-i-restart-my-program-in-python-see-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop to repeat until a certain condition is met.

```
value = input("Type 'generate' to generate a new password or 'quit' to quit.\n")
while value != 'quit':
    if value == 'generate':
        line = open("words.txt").read()
        line = line[0:] 

        words = line.split() 
        one = random.choice(words)

        line = open("numbers.txt").read()
        line = line[0:]

        numbers = line.split()
        two = random.choice(numbers)

        line = open("words.txt").read()
        line = line[0:]

        words2 = line.split()
        three = random.choice(words2)
        print('Your new password is '+(one)+(two)+(three))
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
    value = input("Type 'generate' to generate a new password or 'quit' to quit.\n")
```

The program will keep repeating until the user enters quit, which will then break the while loop.